# Binding Wpf list

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have some problem to resolve this issue.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridMates" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
```

Whit Binding Groups.
This Groups are composed by :

```
public class Group
{ 
    public List<ClassMate> CLGroup { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

ClassMateclass :

```
public class ClassMate: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }}
```

So I want to show on my datagrid the GroupName and the DisplayName of each ClassMate.

I see GroupName doing this :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridMates"  ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"><DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="GroupName" Binding="{Binding Path=GroupName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DisplayName" Binding="{Binding Path=CLGroup.DisplayName}" />
```

But I can't see right DiplayName.
What is wrong?

Comment: Is there a 'PointsGroup' property on your ' Group' class?

Comment: Wrong code, sorry. Right now

Comment: @SimonLP, CLGroup is a list which can have more than 1 item, and different items can have different DisplayNames. CLGroup list itself doesn't have DisplayName. to  take DisplayName from the first item, for example, use `CLGroup[0].DisplayName` path

Comment: @ASh great, but I would have all my classMate on list, not only the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLGroup` is a List which can have more than 1 item, and different items can have different DisplayNames. CLGroup list itself doesn't have DisplayName. to take DisplayName from the first item, for example, use `CLGroup[0].DisplayName` path.

if you need to show all items, use `DataGridTemplateColumn` with an ItemsControl in a CellTemplate.

both approaches:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="GroupName" Binding="{Binding Path=GroupName}" />

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="DisplayName" Binding="{Binding Path=CLGroup[0].DisplayName}" />

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DisplayName">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CLGroup}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="gridMates"  ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"><DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="GroupName" Binding="{Binding Path=GroupName}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Class Mates">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <DataGrid x:Name="gridClassMates"  ItemsSource="{Binding CLGroup}">
                       <DataGrid.Columns>
                          <DataGridTextColumn Header="DisplayName" Binding="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                       </DataGrid.Columns> 
                   </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```